# What's wrong with this 'find' command?

Tags: command-line, delete, find

I am executing the following command (to find all files with `.ts` extension and deleting them):

```
find . -type f -name "*.ts" –delete
```

An error shows up:

```
find: paths must precede expression: `–delete'
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have typographic sign `–` instead of minus (`-`).

Change your command to

```
find . -type f -name "*.ts" -delete
```

For complete syntax see [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/find.1.html):

> **ACTIONS**
>          `-delete`
>
> Delete  files;  true if removal succeeded.  If the removal failed, an error message is issued.
>           If `-delete`  fails,  `find`'s  exit  status  will  be  nonzero  (when  it eventually exits).
>           Use of `-delete` automatically turns on the `-depth` option.

---

Be careful with copying and pasting commands from blogs and rich text processors. They may transform some typographic symbols to their plain text equivalents and vice versa.

Consider to use simple text editors for the notes next time - use plain text, Markdown or reStructuredText.

And as @AuxTaco mentioned - [some blogs may rely on your copying to attack your computer](https://thejh.net/misc/website-terminal-copy-paste).

Comment: [And some blogs may rely on your copying to attack your computer.](https://thejh.net/misc/website-terminal-copy-paste)

Comment: In this particular case we do not know the source of this command. If original author wrongly had `--` then engine converted it to `–`. So we do not know the whole story :)

Comment: I can tell the story: I copy-pasted it from terminal to a MS Word document consisted of command set to deploy our server. MS Word is auto-fixing the dash in some cases. Then a year or some after i copied that command and the question opened...
Thanks.

Comment: @Dorad such "fixing" causes no end of trouble with copy/pasting code snippets.  One trick is to pre-format a one-line block of placeholder text like "[code sample]", set whatever indentation, font etc., then paste in the plain text from the terminal and _click somewhere away from the pasted selection_.   This should prevent Word from "fixing" your "mistakes".

Comment: It's probably better to use Notepad++ in this situation, rather than Word.

Comment: Never use a word processor to edit code. That's (a big reason) why there are still text editors. The last thing you need is substituted characters, or word wrap.